# XSLT transformation adding namespace from child to parent

Tags: xslt

I am trying to xslt transformation for multiple response files.

I have one input xml :

`

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ser-root:getAllAreasResponse xmlns:ser-root="http://ws.dm.gov.ae/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<return>
<ns1:Area xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EP4.Integration.Entities.Common">
<ns1:Identity>451</ns1:Identity>
<ns1:NameAr>الحبيه الخامسة</ns1:NameAr>
<ns1:NameEn>Al Hebiah Fifth</ns1:NameEn>
</ns1:Area>
<ns1:Area xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EP4.Integration.Entities.Common">
<ns1:Identity>451</ns1:Identity>
<ns1:NameAr>الحبيه الخامسة</ns1:NameAr>
<ns1:NameEn>Al Hebiah Fifth</ns1:NameEn>
</ns1:Area>
</return>
</ser-root>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`

I want output like below.

`

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns2:getAllAreasResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.dm.gov.ae/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EP4.Integration.Entities.Common">
<return>
<ns3:Area >
<ns3:Identity>451</ns3:Identity>
<ns3:NameAr>الحبيه الخامسة</ns3:NameAr>
<ns3:NameEn>Al Hebiah Fifth</ns3:NameEn>
</ns3:Area>
<ns3:Area >
<ns3:Identity>452</ns3:Identity>
<ns3:NameAr>الحبيه الثانية</ns3:NameAr>
<ns3:NameEn>Al Hebiah Second</ns3:NameEn>
</ns3:Area>
```

`

How to write xslt for that?

Answer (score 1):

To change namespace prefixes without changing namespace URIs you can use code like this in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="soapenv:*"  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:element name="S:{local-name()}" namespace="namespace-uri()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Define one such template rule for each namespace.

In 1.0, in place of `soapenv:*` use `*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/']`